# Resize tile based on variable in Heatmap

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a dataframe for which I have constructed a heatmap, shown below:

```
df <- data.frame("CELL1" = c(0.7,0.7,0.5 ), 
             "CELL2" = c(1, 0.4, 0.3), 
             "CELL3" = c(0.7, 0.73, 0.61))
#set rownames
rownames(df) <- c("GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3")

#plot
heatmap.2(as.matrix(df), scale = "column",Rowv=TRUE, Colv=TRUE, 
          trace = "none",  distfun = dist,
          hclustfun = hclust, 
          margins=c(20,20))
```

[image]

I want to change this heatmap, such that the size of each tile is based on numbers in another dataframe, with identical column and rownames, but different values. Such that, gene 1-cell1 would have a large tile, while gene 1, cell2 would have a smaller tile. Shown below:

```
#Create df
df2 <- data.frame("CELL1" = c(183,2,19 ), 
                 "CELL2" = c(24, 1.8, 11.1), 
                 "CELL3" = c(18.9, 3.3, 22.9))
rownames(df2) <- c("GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3")
 
> df2
      CELL1 CELL2 CELL3
GENE1   183  24.0  18.9
GENE2     2   1.8   3.3
GENE3    19  11.1  22.9
```

How can I do this? Is this even possible? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes sense, but if you change the size of tiles it won't look like a heatmap anymore, eg:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
# Create dataframes
df <- data.frame("Gene" = c("GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3"),
                 "CELL1" = c(0.7, 0.7, 0.5), 
                 "CELL2" = c(1, 0.4, 0.3), 
                 "CELL3" = c(0.7, 0.73, 0.61))
df2 <- data.frame("Gene" = c("GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3"),
                  "CELL1" = c(183, 2, 19), 
                  "CELL2" = c(24, 1.8, 11.1), 
                  "CELL3" = c(18.9, 3.3, 22.9))
# Pivot df1 to 'long' format
data <- pivot_longer(data = df, cols = c(CELL1, CELL2, CELL3))
# Pivot df2 to 'long' format and scale values
data2 <- pivot_longer(data = df2, cols = c(CELL1, CELL2, CELL3)) %>%
  mutate(value = log10(value)/1.5)
# Plot "data" using "data2" to set the tile sizes
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = name, y = Gene)) +
  geom_tile(data = data2, aes(fill = value, width = value, height = value)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image: mangled_heatmap]

So I'm not sure what use this will be to you, but if this is what you're trying to do I'll see if it's possible using `heatmap.2`, or I could add the dendrogram etc to this plot and see how it looks.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, is there a way to make sure the tiles don't overlap (they seem to do so if the width is large enough.

Comment: The only way I know to make sure the tiles don't overlap is to scale the size of the tiles, e.g. `geom_tile(data = data2, aes(fill = value, height = value / 150, width = value / 150))`